# Узнать координаты центра города по названию

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет интересует следующий вопрос есть переменная в которой занесено название города, например, Москва. Как с помощью яндекс карт узнать координаты центра Москвы. Широту и долготу. Прочитал уже кучу API документации но так и не могу сообразить как это сделать...

Код следующий

При изменении списка делаем

```
$('.select1').change(function(){
    var city = $(".selected1").text(); // Выбираем выбраный город получаем его название

    // Тут нужно получить кординаты с использованием переменной city и занести их в переменные шырота и долгота

});
```

Помогите кто сталкивался подобной задачей

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Поиск по карте](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/dg/concepts/geocoding.xml)

```
var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(city);
myGeocoder.then(
    function (res) {
        alert('Координаты объекта :' + res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
    },
    function (err) {
        alert('Ошибка');
    }
);
```